# Plots lines disappear in Tikz when inserting an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot

In the following TikZ plot, the plot lines disappear when an image is inserted. I need the plot line to be seen along with the image to appear behind these plot lines. The following is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68,font=\bfseries]
                \begin{axis}[title=Area of intrest, every axis title/.append style={at={(0.5,1.1)}}, ylabel near ticks, ymin=100,ymax=120,y tick label style={font=\boldmath},  xlabel near ticks,  xlabel=centered area, x tick label style={font=\boldmath},axis on top, ylabel=Millimeters per year, ymajorgrids=true,grid style=dashed,legend entries={A1, B2,C3 ,D4},
                    legend columns=5,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.15,-0.3)},
                        anchor=south west,legend style={draw=none}},every axis/.append style={semithick},every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},enlarge x limits=false,enlarge y limits=false, clip = false,]
                    \addplot [color=magenta,mark=square*,mark size=1.7pt] coordinates {(-6,113)(-5.5,113.8)(-5,110.1)(-4.5,111)(-3,119)(0,118.6)(3,119.5)(4.5,111)(5,109)(5.5,108)(6,103.9)};
                    \addplot [color=red, mark=pentagon*]  coordinates {(-6,105)(-5.5,109)(-5,111)(-4.5,111.9)(-3,118)(0,118.7)(3,119.6)(4.5,112.1)(5,111.6)(5.5,105.8)(6,102.9)};
                    \addplot [color=green, mark=otimes*]  coordinates {(-6,110.4)(-5.5,112.6)(-5,113.4)(-4.5,111.2)(-3,114.7)(0,114.9)(3,114.3)(4.5,113.6)(5,112.4)(5.5,111.6)(6,109)};
                    \addplot graphics
                    [xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=100,ymax=120]
                    {example-image-a};
                    \draw[red, |<->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0) -- node[above] {Variable} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.246, 0);
                    \draw[red, |->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.25, 0) -- node[above] {\tiny Marginal} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0, 0);
                    \draw[red, |<-,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:1, 0) -- node[above] { \tiny Marginal   } ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0);
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The required out should be as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the image covering up the lines if you plot it first:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68,font=\bfseries]
                \begin{axis}[title=Area of intrest, every axis title/.append style={at={(0.5,1.1)}}, ylabel near ticks, ymin=100,ymax=120,y tick label style={font=\boldmath},  xlabel near ticks,  xlabel=centered area, x tick label style={font=\boldmath},axis on top, ylabel=Millimeters per year, ymajorgrids=true,grid style=dashed,legend entries={A1, B2,C3 ,D4},
                    legend columns=5,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.15,-0.3)},
                        anchor=south west,legend style={draw=none}},every axis/.append style={semithick},every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},enlarge x limits=false,enlarge y limits=false, clip = false,]
                    \addplot graphics [xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=100,ymax=120]{example-image-a};
                    \addplot [color=magenta,mark=square*,mark size=1.7pt] coordinates {(-6,113)(-5.5,113.8)(-5,110.1)(-4.5,111)(-3,119)(0,118.6)(3,119.5)(4.5,111)(5,109)(5.5,108)(6,103.9)};
                    \addplot [color=red, mark=pentagon*]  coordinates {(-6,105)(-5.5,109)(-5,111)(-4.5,111.9)(-3,118)(0,118.7)(3,119.6)(4.5,112.1)(5,111.6)(5.5,105.8)(6,102.9)};
                    \addplot [color=green, mark=otimes*]  coordinates {(-6,110.4)(-5.5,112.6)(-5,113.4)(-4.5,111.2)(-3,114.7)(0,114.9)(3,114.3)(4.5,113.6)(5,112.4)(5.5,111.6)(6,109)};
                    \draw[red, |<->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0) -- node[above] {Variable} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.246, 0);
                    \draw[red, |->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.25, 0) -- node[above] {\tiny Marginal} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0, 0);
                    \draw[red, |<-,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:1, 0) -- node[above] { \tiny Marginal   } ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0);
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be observed that in the legend entry, a new entry for plot graphics is registered, and to remove it from legend entry the following can be done.

`\addplot[draw=none,forget plot][xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=100,ymax=120]{example-image-a};`

complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68,font=\bfseries]
                \begin{axis}[title=Area of intrest, every axis title/.append style={at={(0.5,1.1)}}, ylabel near ticks, ymin=100,ymax=120,y tick label style={font=\boldmath},  xlabel near ticks,  xlabel=centered area, x tick label style={font=\boldmath},axis on top, ylabel=Millimeters per year, ymajorgrids=true,grid style=dashed,legend entries={A1, B2,C3 ,D4},
                    legend columns=5,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.15,-0.3)},
                        anchor=south west,legend style={draw=none}},every axis/.append style={semithick},every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},enlarge x limits=false,enlarge y limits=false, clip = false,]
                    \addplot[draw=none,forget plot] graphics [xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=100,ymax=120]{example-image-a};
                    \addplot [color=magenta,mark=square*,mark size=1.7pt] coordinates {(-6,113)(-5.5,113.8)(-5,110.1)(-4.5,111)(-3,119)(0,118.6)(3,119.5)(4.5,111)(5,109)(5.5,108)(6,103.9)};
                    \addplot [color=red, mark=pentagon*]  coordinates {(-6,105)(-5.5,109)(-5,111)(-4.5,111.9)(-3,118)(0,118.7)(3,119.6)(4.5,112.1)(5,111.6)(5.5,105.8)(6,102.9)};
                    \addplot [color=green, mark=otimes*]  coordinates {(-6,110.4)(-5.5,112.6)(-5,113.4)(-4.5,111.2)(-3,114.7)(0,114.9)(3,114.3)(4.5,113.6)(5,112.4)(5.5,111.6)(6,109)};
                    \draw[red, |<->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0) -- node[above] {Variable} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.246, 0);
                    \draw[red, |->|,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.25, 0) -- node[above] {\tiny Marginal} ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0, 0);
                        \node[draw=none,fill=none,text opacity=1] (scale) at (0.8cm,6.5cm) {\textbf{ AS}};
                    \draw[red, |<-,thick] ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:1, 0) -- node[above] { \tiny Marginal   } ([yshift = 6cm] axis description cs:0.753, 0);
                        \node[draw=none,fill=none,text opacity=1] (scale) at (5.8cm,6.5cm) {\textbf{ RS}};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```